"Linear independency" of Lie Brackets
I was watching this eigenchris video. At 21:49, he says:
$$[g_i, g_j]=\sum_k {f_{ij}}^{k}g_k$$
for $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.
Does this mean $[g_i, g_j]$ and $g_i, g_j$ can be linear independent? What about different kinds of basis (maybe spherical coordinates)? Since Lie algebra is defined as tangent space it can have many dimensions which seem to support the thought given the $f'(0)$ of $gAg^-1$ definition of Lie bracket? I'm confused.

Have you studied ladder operators?

The same frame also mentions that, for example, $[g_1,g_2]=g_3$, where (I assume) ${g_1,g_2,g_3}$ is a basis for $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, so clearly they can be linearly independent

Have heard of ladder operators but not studied until yesterday I finished mathemaniac Lie group series when I feel like cleared some confusion and moved on with eigenchris series.
I watched some more videos and I found the bivector explanation. So I suppose these ladder operators and their commutator can be whatever they are as bivector basis' and as Lie algebra is literally defined on brackets they all still live in the Lie algebra?

Yes, indeed they always will be whatever basis you choose in the case of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ although this is a more in depth result and not true for every Lie algebra.
Obviously the structure equations would be different for a different basis but they would have to have the property that $[e_i, e_j]$ is either $0$ or linearly independent to $e_i,e_j$. The reason being that $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is compact and subalgebras of compact Lie algebras are themselves compact but the two dimensional Lie algebra defined by the rule $[x,y] = ax+by$ is noncompact (it is solvable but not abelian so can't be compact) so we cannot find it anywhere in $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.
Edit: on reflection $[e_i,e_j] = 0$ is not possible either as the maximum dimension of an abelian subalgebra is $1$ for $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ but this would be different for a larger compact Lie algebra.
For noncompact Lie algebras we have no such property indeed $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ the Lie algebra of trace-free matrices contains $h=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ and $e=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $[h,e] = 2e$.
I'm not sure that the tangent space definition of a Lie algebra comes into the picture here though.

So for the angular momentum ladder operator case there is a two to one homomorphism from su(2) to so(3) algebra but so(3) cannot be broken down further into subalgebra which has linear dependent Lie bracket, therefore the ladder operators must exist in a noncompact Lie algebra sl(2, C) (instead of its retraction su(2)?) such that the subalgebra defined by [g_z, g_+]=g_+ may exist.

@Cro $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ are the same Lie algebra. It is the Lie groups which have a relationship as you describe. I'm not really sure how we would talk about ladder operators in a compact Lie algebra as there are no root vectors that actually live in the Lie algebra and "ladder operator" is just a way of describing the way root vectors act. Furthermore $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is a real form of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ not a retraction (again that is a Lie group thing)

Maybe $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is the same because the "positive" and the "negative" of SU(2) that get sent to SO(3) are not "neighbours" and when we choose a slice it's exactly the same?
I think root vectors is exactly the phrase I'm looking for, I'll look it up, thx

Wait I think root vector just means eigenvector, or can I imagine like having eigenvector meaning I can scale however I want therefore cannot be bounded thus noncompact?

I think I'll find my answer reading Erdmann&Wildon chapter 10

@Cro Sort of. More accurately the groups are locally isomorphic. As to eigenvectors and compactness, this is actually not far away from the right idea. However note that no vector space (and thus no Lie algebra) is bounded, you could always rescale any vector. It is true though that the image of a root space under the exponential map is non-compact. Note applying the exponential map to the span of the Pauli matrices you instead get a circle in the Lie group which of course is compact.
